# Нахождение простых чисел от 0 до 100 на mysql

Tags: mysql

```
select id from nums where id>1 and id not in 
(   select distinct n2id 
    from 
    (   select n1.id as n1id, n2.id as n2id 
        from nums n1 
        cross join nums n2 
        where n1.id<(n2.id) and n1.id>1 and (n2.id MOD n1.id = 0) 
    ) xDerived 
) 
order by id;
```

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Простые числа - они не меньше 2, так что "от нуля" - не имеет смысла.

Comment: А в чём вопрос-то? В первой редакции вопрос был, зачем вы его стёрли?

Comment: Запрос, конечно, угробищный... сперва выберем все составные, потом выберем все, не входящие в этот список. И этот ужастик - вместо логичного и лаконичного WHERE NOT EXISTS...